# How to get on which ListView has been a ContextItem selected?

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity with three listviews, each having three different cursors, but all have the same ContextMenu show/resolve code and when the selection event fires, I want to get the ListView to refresh it.

I can't use `menuInfo.targetView`, as that holds the LinearLayout for the ListView row, and not the ListView.

in this method

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

How is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching `Tag`s/Holders to row `View`s in `Adapter`s, right?
Have a Tag class per Adapter.
Now,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        Class<?> tagClass = info.targetView.getTag().getClass();
        if(tagClass == FirstTag.class){
            // the first list
        } else if(tagClass == SecondTag.class){
            // the second one
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('I've screwed up this hack.');
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: This method is good and usable, although getting the ListView would be the best. I hope someone will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Use MenuInfo, passed as the third argument of `onCreateContextMenu()`. You could add a reference to your ListView, for example. You can query it by `item.getMenuInfo()`.

**Edit:** sorry, there isn't a way to set MenuInfo.
Try creating the context menu items with different groupIDs for each listView, then you can switch  based `onMenuItem.getGroupId()`.

Comment: How do I pass that ListView forward to `onContextItemSelected` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try `menuInfo.targetView.getParent()` - this is the ListView itself.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I was wrong.Several ListView will work together on the same screen. Might be challenging due to real estate but will work.

Comment: This answer doesn't relates to the problem. Don't make up things that the OP doesn't told, ask before. The ListViews are on separate Tabs, UI is consistent, and again it's not the problem I am facing.

Comment: Also don't forget that Android can be use on set-top boxes like TVs, where having multiple scrollable areas is different.

Comment: If your ListViews are on separate tabs, then you can determine which tab you're on (TabHost.getCurrentTab()) so you'll now which ListView to refresh.

Comment: I was definitely wrong. Multiplay list/grid view will be fine as long as they not wrapped up in the ScrollView.